# How can i get method level transaction time out in ejb?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, ejb, weblogic12c

In my *EJB* application, I have set transaction time for a session out in *`weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`* to 6000 seconds, but there is a method in this session bean for which I need only 60 seconds timeout.

How can I get method level transaction timeout in *EJB*?

Answer (score 0):

You can set transaction time out in method level:- 
Use below code , Its will help you

```
    @AccessTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {

   // Write your code here 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Is there any other way other than using annotations ???? , cause in our application we are not using annotations , rather than that , we are using xmls

Comment: Annotation is also method please check this method and implement  its will be work